# C# converting to and from Unix time - 1 day lost

Tags: c#, .net-core

here is the code:

```
var date = DateTime.Now.Date;
var ms = (long)(date - DateTimeOffset.UnixEpoch).TotalMilliseconds;
var date1 = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(ms).DateTime.Date;
```

date is 24th and date1 is 23rd

why dont they match?

Comment: Probably timezones. `DateTme.Now` is in your `Local` timezone. `DateTimeOffset.UnixEpoch` is in UTC. Doing `date - DateTimeOffset.UnixEpoch` will do the timezone conversion, so that `ms` gives the number of seconds since the unix epoch (UTC) to "now" in your local timezone. All good so far. `DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(ms)` gives you a `DateTimeOffset` in UTC, so `date1` will be in UTC, not your local timezone. From this, we gather that you must be ahead of UTC?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(ms).LocalDateTime`.

`DateTime.Now` has `Kind = Local` so it is eskewing your UTC offset.

You can see it with:

```
var kind = DateTime.Now.Date.Kind;
```

and then you can make a small test with the "kind":

```
var date = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Local);
var ms = (long)(date - DateTimeOffset.UnixEpoch).TotalMilliseconds;
```

How much `ms` is? Depending on winter/summer time and your location, it probably isn't 0.

So your `ms` includes your UTC offset. Now you have to:

```
var date1 = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(ms).LocalDateTime;
```

and let's hope you are still in the "original" utc offset (so not enough days have passed between the calculation of `date` and the calculation of `date1` for you to switch between winter/summer time)

(if you did everything correctly, you don't really need the `.Date` after `.LocalDateTime`, because the date should already be `00:00:00`)

Comment: what you said - it works. But I dont understand why. I am only 2hrs apart from UTC..

Comment: @BoppityBop And those two hours push the 00:00 time to 22:00 time of the day previous. There is no "pure Date" type in C#. With the `.Date` you simply put the time to 00:00.

Comment: @BoppityBop Exactly. Don't forget you're doing `DateTime.Now.Date` -- that `.Date` is important, as it gives you a `DateTime` representing midnight on the day in question

Comment: As a rant, the Kind information in DateTime is one of the worst ideas they put in .NET 1.0, and sadly we have to keep it. I've only seen it break things, and I haven't ever seen it as something useful.

Comment: Agreed. Use `DateTimeOffset` where possible (there are only rare cases where it doesn't make sense to use it), and consider something like NodaTime for those cases where `DateTimeOffset` doesn't cut it